# RE2 failed to match easy pattern

Tags: regex, re2

Using simple regexp with re2j library with Spring (Java) project. In debug mode I found out that pattern:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F:]+$
```

It compiled, but failed to recognize text:

```
123ABC:DEF456
0:1:2:3:4:5
12345
90210-1234
```

Expecting that pattern matched text, but hasMatch = false

Comment: Plausibly a typo?  Try, _^[-0-9a-fA-F:]+$_.

Comment: Missed the `MULTILINE` flag? `(?m)^[0-9a-fA-F:]+$`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew thanks a lot!
Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.MULTILINE) solved issue

Comment: It still doesn't match the text ... lol.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems with your current pattern.  First, it appears that the separator character could be either `:` or `-`, but your pattern only caters to the former.  Also, if you want to match many such strings across multiple lines, then you need to take that into account.

Try this version:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]+(?:[:-][0-9a-fA-F]+)*(?:\r?\n[0-9a-fA-F]+(?:[:-][0-9a-fA-F]+)*)*$
```

### Demo

If you only need to match one line at time, then simplify to:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]+(?:[:-][0-9a-fA-F]+)*$
```

Comment: thank you for answer. Actually, I'm testing my Pattern and if I checking it in regexp101 - it matches 3 times. I expected that.
I don't need to change pattern or text. I need to understand, why RE2 didn't match

Comment: `90210-1234` will _not_ match your regex pattern, using any engine AFAIK.  Maybe then only the first part of my answer is relevant.

Comment: you can see, that 3 from 4  matches https://regex101.com/r/WoMDkS/1

Comment: @RUSLANSIMAKOV I don't see where you are having doubts here.  Your pattern does not match dash, so how can the 4th input possibly be matched?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [@Wiktor Stribiżew's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476501/re2-failed-to-match-easy-pattern/77476763#comment136587189_77476501):

> Missed the `MULTILINE` flag? `(?m)^[0-9a-fA-F:]+$`

This solved the issue:

```
Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.MULTILINE)
```